# how can I solve error while reading Excel xls file in java

Tags: java, excel

I have a Excel file in the location called **E:/portfolio.xls**. I want to read this file through a java code. I wrote some of the code using java but not able to read that file and showing some error.I am new in these type of coding. Some one please help me to solve these problem.My java code is in bellow:

/SampleExcelReading.java

```
package com.sampleexcelreading.core;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class SampleExcelReading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {

                Multimap<String, String> portfolioHoldingMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();   



                File f=new File("E:/portfolio.xls");
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f);

                int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet=null; 

                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                String currentSchemeNameCode = "";
                String holding_date = "";

                while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                     Row row = rowIterator.next();

                     int rowNo = row.getRowNum();

                     if(rowNo < 0 || rowNo >= 1500)
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                         while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                         {
                             Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                             String value = "";
                             switch (cell.getCellType())
                             {
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                     if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) 
                                     {
                                         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                         value = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                                     } 
                                     else 
                                     {
                                         value = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                     }
                                     break;
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                     value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                     break;
                                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                     value = "0";
                                     break;
                                 default:
                                     value = "0";
                                     break;
                             }

                             if(cell.getColumnIndex() == 0 && rowNo > 0 && !value.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                             {                       
                                 value = value.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
                                 int firstHypenIndex = value.indexOf("-");                       
                                 value = value.substring(firstHypenIndex + 2, value.length());                       
                                 int firstAsAtIndex = value.indexOf(" as at ");                      
                                 holding_date = value.substring(firstAsAtIndex + 7, value.length());                     
                                 String[] nav_date_splitted = holding_date.split("[\\/]+");
                                 holding_date = nav_date_splitted[2] + "-" + nav_date_splitted[1] + "-" + nav_date_splitted[0];                      
                                 value = value.substring(0, firstAsAtIndex);                     
                                 value = value.replaceAll("'","ï¿½");                
                                 schemeName.add(value.trim());
                                 currentSchemeNameCode = value.trim();
                             }

                             if(rowNo == 0 && cell.getColumnIndex() != 0)
                             {
                                 value = value.replaceAll("'","ï¿½");
                                 companyName.add(value);
                             }


                             if(rowNo > 0 && cell.getColumnIndex() != 0)
                             { 
                                 portfolioHoldingMap.put(currentSchemeNameCode,cell.getColumnIndex() + "||" + value.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ") + "||" + holding_date);
                             }

                         }
                     }


         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }           

    }

}
```

/* Here is my Error */

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:91)
    at com.advisorkhoj.amfi.SampleExcelReading.main(SampleExcelReading.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Characters larger than 4 bytes are not supported: byte 0x96 implies a length of more than 4 bytes
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.UTF8XMLDecoder.decode(UTF8XMLDecoder.java:162)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader$FastStreamDecoder.read(XMLStreamReader.java:762)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader.read(XMLStreamReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yy_refill(PiccoloLexer.java:3474)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:3958)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.StyleSheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.readFrom(StylesTable.java:121)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:92)
    ... 10 more
```

/My jar files are

```
dom4j-1.6.jar
poi-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-betal1.jar
xmlbeans-2.30.jar
```

Comment: I would start by reducing code and xls sheet. It could well be that the xls contains data the tool doesn't know how to handle.

Comment: if possible upgrade to .xlsx type as it supports more features

Comment: so, how can I solve this type of problem

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI has only partial support to read Excel xlsb files. It can't be done using a Workbook, but since POI 3.16-beta3 it supports streaming reading of such files via [XSSFBReader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFBReader.html).